# Is there a such thing as a double right-click in Win32?

Tags: winapi, windows-messages

I haven't found anything mentioning a double right-click windows message but am curious if anybody knows of events that fire for a double right-click.

Any ideas?

Comment: Pretty sure there is no native double right-click. You could roll your own by measuring the time between clicks.

Comment: Wow... that's so weird!!

Comment: @Betamoo: It's not weird -- just wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646241.aspx).