# How do I implement a double-right-click for winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042143/is-there-a-such-thing-as-a-double-right-click-in-win32) seems to point to the existence of a windows event for a double-right-click. How to implement it in a C# windows form, however, is less than clear.

What's the best way to implement double-right-click on a control such as a button?

(I'm thinking I must use `MouseDown` and keep track of the time between clicks. Is there a better way?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override the `WndProc` function and listen for `WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK`, which as can be seen on this [pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/WindowsMessages.html) page is `0x0206`.

That pinvoke page also has some C# sample code for how to do it.

Whenever you see something about a windows message and/or windows API and you want to use it in C#, the pinvoke site is a good place to start looking.

Answer (score 3):

Override [Control.WndProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc.aspx), and handle the [WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646241(VS.85).aspx) message manually.

Answer (score 2):

MouseEventArgs contain property 'Button' that indicate wich button was clicked. So you can simply check this:

```
    private void MouseDoubleClickEventHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            DoSomthing();
        } else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            DoSomethingElse();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement this by inheriting from a button and overriding `WndProc` as ho1 and Reed suggested. Here's the inherited button:

```
public class RButton : Button
{
    public delegate void MouseDoubleRightClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e);
    public event MouseDoubleRightClick DoubleRightClick;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        const Int32 WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0206;
        if (m.Msg == WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK)
            DoubleRightClick(this, null);
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

I added the button programatically to the form and subscribed to its new DoubleRightClick event. I'm not sure how exactly to generate the appropriate `MouseEventArgs` but since this is just a test case, it's not important.